# JavaScript: Choosing dropdown list items using Page Objects for Protractor testing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, protractor, pageobjects

So I can't figure this one out.

My test calls for choosing a list item as part of a form to create a new user. However, when I run the test it does not choose an item from the list. And Protractor doesn't return any errors, it thinks the test was a success.

The function I was using previously worked, but in an effort to reduce code repetition, and increase fluidity and flexibility I have started converting the test to incorporate Page Objects.

Below is my test document which shows the functions being called in from two different page objects:

```
it('Should create first new User.', function() {
    var users_page = require('../page/users_page.js');
    var addUser_page = require('../page/addUser_page.js');
    users_page.addUserButton.click();
    addUser_page.addUser('Test', 'Smith', 'Test100@testing.co.nz', 'Password', 'Password', '0');
    addUser_page.userRole[1];
    addUser_page.confirmNewUser.click();
    addUser_page.backToUsersPage.click();
});
```

Everything works here apart from line 6 - choosing a list item.

Below is the snippet from the page object I refer to when calling the .userRole function:

```
this.userRole = function (index) {
    this.element(by.model('tes.userRole')).$('[value="'+index+'"]');
};
```

NOTE: There is NOT a problem with the Page Objects talking to the test as there are multiple other functions that DO work.

Let me know if you need any more information, cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this problem a few times; if you want to click the object you'll need to write something like this in your Page Object:

```
this.clickUserRoleByIndex = function (index) {
    this.element(by.model('tes.userRole')).$('[value="'+index+'"]').click();
};
```

OR what I think you want to do...

You can do something like this to get that object:

```
this.getUserRoleByIndex = function (index) {
    return this.element(by.model('tes.userRole')).$('[value="'+index+'"]');
};
```

Note the **return** gives you that object to then interact with in the full test - I got bitten by it before I realised that of course it'll be undefined unless I return something in that function!

Hope that helps! :D